# Generic method for callback to IOS/Android Application Layer from Native Layer (CPP)

Tags: android, c++, ios

I have Mobile Application projects for IOS & Android which internally uses the same Native cpp code. IOS project calls the Native file 'MyNativeFile.cpp' from 'MyApplication.m'. Android project calls the Native file 'MyNativeFile.cpp' through 'MyActivity.java' (Application Layer) via 'MyJNIInterface.cpp' (JNI Interface).

I need a generic implementation in my Native layer file 'MyNativeFile.cpp' through which some char string type data in Native layer can be sent to Application Layers (IOS/Android). (Please note that if I use JNI callback methods like the one mentioned in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jniCallback it would not work for IOS environment)

My Android Application has below files

1. MyActivity.java (Application Layer)
2. MyJNIInterface.cpp (JNI Interface)
3. MyNativeFile.cpp (Native implementation)

My IOS Project has below files

1. MyApplication.m (Application Layer)
2. MyNativeFile.cpp (Native implementation)

One way of doing this is writing the character string to a file from Native code & then reading the same file in Application layer. But this method will have performance issues.

Please suggest a good way for doing this. Share some sample code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I am doing such a project where strings, integer arrays and other longer data types have to be returned.

> I need a generic implementation in my Native layer file
>   'MyNativeFile.cpp' through which some char string type data in Native
>   layer can be sent to Application Layers

A method for your problem of returning a string can be solved by a *reference to string*, in your **.cpp** file, the function should have a parameter of a pointer to a character array, i.e, `std::string & varName`.

In this parameter, be it your .m file in **iOS or JNI in JAVA**, all you have to do is first declare an empty in string. Then pass this empty string while you call your function.

The header file of my project is as follows.

```
//.h file
class FindData {

public:
    void findDataPt(int corrOut, string &result_array);
//In this function make changes to result_array directly and they'll reflect on the original string too
};
```

To call this from **.m**, I *IMPORT THE .h* first and then do the following in iOS:

Note: Make the .m as .mm to include C++ includes and functionality

```
//ViewController.mm

#include <string>
viewDidLoad{

string varName;
FindData fd;
fd. findDataPt(15,varName);

}
```

After this, make changes to the string, in findDataPt function.